# ngroute working but Controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ngRoute work but i can't display model in the view.
it seems that the controller is not detected correctly.
when i run this example i get the below result. 
First user :
    username: {{ user.username }}
    rating :{{ user.rating }}

```js
/* file user.js*/
var app= angular.module('userApp',['ngRoute']);

app.controller('userListController', function($scope){    

    $scope.users=[
 {
     "username": "Bryant",
     "rating": 37
 },
 {
     "username": "Wells",
     "rating": 1
 },
 {
     "username": "Sims",
     "rating": 4
 },
 {
     "username": "Blankenship",
     "rating": 37
 },
 {
     "username": "Simon",
     "rating": 11
 },
 {
     "username": "Reyes",
     "rating": 9
 },
 {
     "username": "Malone",
     "rating": 17
 },
 {
     "username": "Evans",
     "rating": 25
 },
 {
     "username": "Keller",
     "rating": 32
 }
    ];


});

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: '/home.html'}).when('/members', {templateUrl: '/members.html',controller:'userListController'}).otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

});
```

```html
<!--file mermbers.html -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users"> First user :
        <ul>
       <li> username: {{ user.username }}</li>
       <li>rating :{{ user.rating }}</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>

<!-- file index.html-->

<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="userApp">
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="user.js"></script>
 

  </head>
  <body ng-app="userApp">

    
  
      <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: such output is typical for a catastrophic failure of the application. What does console log say?

Comment: Btw, check this one. I've put your code to plunker and modified it to show members view at root. it kinda works. So controller is fine.
[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/1eVJxGNle53fs4ebU5Ag?p=preview)

Comment: thank you vladimir,  my console does not display any errors i can't found the problem

Comment: have you followed the plunker link?

Comment: i found the problem thank you again vladimir. i redirect the view in the main page with "/members.html"  instead "/members"

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `ng-app="userApp"` twice (in HTML and BODY). 
Maybe you need to declare `ng-controller="userListController"` in BODY instead.

Check the console output searching for errors when loading your page.

Comment: yes i duplicate the ng-app, but removing the duplicate ng-app not resolve my problem, the declaration of ng-controller is set in the route provider :..when('/members', {templateUrl: '/members.html',controller:'userListController'}). and finaly i don't see any errors in the console